# UI using OpenGL

Tags: android, user-interface, opengl-es

I've been given a task of designing an app in android with the UI created in OpenGL. The reason for this approach is the fact that the app will be a port from iPhone and Android does not have such smooth animations and graphics as IOS.

I have experience in Android development but I'm totaly new to OpenGL.

Is that approach reasonable to create GUI in OpenGL? If not, why? If yes, how do I start?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is your application a game? because if not, I think using OpenGl just for creating a fancy UI might be too much. It leaves the door open to do things inefficiently, and probably, get a lot of bugs.
You can get a lot fo smootth animations using [the different animations of Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html).
If you still want to go with OpenGl, I will first advice you to start with [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. The app is not a game but my client has high expectations regarding UI graphics quality. Currently we have a version of the app designed with the traditional approach. Due to large numbers of bitmaps being loaded we get outofmemory exception at some point. The client does not allow any decrease in bitmap quality or number of bitmaps being loaded and he is not happy with animation smoothness.

Comment: Supposedly with OpenGL it is possible to go around the problem of memory allocation limit per thread as described here http://goo.gl/pCYrDM.